# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, php

I had this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
> http://domain.com/canvas/include/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js.
> Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I have these 2 lines at the top of my php page that load this js file.

```
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
```

But the issues persist, what should I do.

I am trying to access

```
domain.com  js file from subdomain.domain.com
```

This is my header response

> access-control-allow-origin:* Connection:Keep-Alive
>
> Content-Encoding:gzip Content-Length:4799 Content-Type:text/html
>
> Date:Wed, 25 May 2016 06:28:04 GMT Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
>
> Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Vary:Host,Accept-Encoding
>
> X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14

Comment: Try `header("access-control-allow-origin: *");`

Comment: Both domains are in your control?

Comment: Try what @Rayon suggest, just note that it isn't always best practice allowing any origin.

Comment: Both are in my control, with root access, I updated my question with Rayon suggestion. 1 is sub.domain.com, another is domain.com, I trying load domain.com js files from subdomain.domain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add access controll on htaccess from origin domain.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

**Is not secure to allow access controll for the all sites. So replace the "*" sign with a specific domain**